# django поле загрузки папки

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Делаю проект на django столкнулся с следующей проблемой: Необходимо, чтобы пользователь выбрал со своего локального пк определенную папку , в которой может содержаться неопределенное количество папок или других файлов, и эта выбранная папка загрузилась на обработку.

Как это можно реализовать? (в последствии надо вывести будет структуру загруженной папки, чтобы пользователь выбрал необходимый файл для обработки)

Comment: https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser - пойдёт? :)

Comment: Боюсь, что браузеры не позволят это сделать

Comment: @andreymal что именно не позволят? Не понятно, о какой обработке идёт речь...  То, что касается filebrowser - это наиболее полное и лучшее то, что реализовано в django с точки зрения обработки файлов через браузер в django. Лучшее вряд ли можно предложить в рамках столь короткого вопроса.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич не позволят выбрать целую папку вместо отдельных файлов. Я ни разу не слышал о такой возможности

Comment: @andreymal имхо автор сам не понимает, что действительно нельзя указывать просто каталог с точки зрения безопасности. У браузера нет такого понятия, как каталог для передачи вовне, и всякие попытки получить значение локальной директории вообще говоря должны пресекаться как нарушение безопасности.

Comment: Теоретически можно написать на javascript запрос доступа к некоторым функциям типа activex.... Но это будет не кроссплатформенно однозначно, либо придется написать свой обработчик для всех поддерживаемых ОС. И это в меньшей степени про django, это про javascript.

Comment: Да, первое что необходимо прочесть автору вопроса - что такое sandbox и  Content Security Policy... В них четко разъясняется что нельзя и главное, почему...

Comment: я новичок ( приходиться учиться сразу на проектах), попробую уточнить вопрос: папка, которую необходимо загрузить - папка с таксономией xbrl, файл  ,который должен быть выбран пользователем одна из xsd-схем лежащих в таксономии, в ней прописаны пути к другим схемам (пример:../../udr/dim/dim-int.xsd) . программа должна обработать первую схему и перейти на вложенные схемы по определенным критериям( данный обработчик в десктоп версии есть). первое - что пришло в голову - загрузить всю таксономию, но не знаю как.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич можно пример реализации формы поля для каталога с данным модулем:github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser?

Comment: @ddsds Там не про каталог, там про файл / группу файлов. Вы максимум можете получить список файлов и файлы, переданный пользователем, но не содержимое каталога который он выбрал. Примеры есть на официальном сайте и в документации. Использую в нескольких проектах, вещь очень удобная. Относительно каталога рекомендую Вам заставить пользователей грузить все необходимое например одним zip архивом. Это не сложно :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич,понял, тогда еще чуть-чуть вопросов, если можно, чем распоковывать полученный архив ? что я получу после распоковки?можно ли это вывести пользоваелю для выбора одного конкретного файла?
и спасибо за советы)

Comment: @ddsds https://gist.github.com/gormih/c72a830ab6b302569b87d45087265a08

Comment: Вывести, естесвенно, можно что угодно. Тут всё зависит от Вашей фантазии :)  В частности в данном случае можно использовать  os и walk чтобы прочесть содержимое, обработать нужным образом и выплюнуть в какой нибудь красивый шаблон с вопросом в форме аля правильно ли мы поняли намерения пользователя.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич,Спасибо!!